# unable to run flutter project after XCode 14.3

Tags: ios, flutter

The project that I'm working right now requires me to have following configurations in my development environment.

flutter - 3.3x

Pod - 1.12.1

Xcode - 14.3x

Before the Xcode update, when it was 14.2, the flutter project was running fine, but the xcode automatically updated itself to 14.3 and now the build fails. When I see the error, I think it is having trouble to find the simulator.

Here is the picture: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7YBY2.png)

```
    Running pod install...
    Running Xcode build...
    Xcode build done.                                            2.3s
    Failed to build iOS app
    Error output from Xcode build:
    ↳
    2023-06-24 00:21:24.163 xcodebuild[96836:1127085] DVTCoreDeviceEnabledState: DVTCoreDeviceEnabledState_Disabled set via user default (DVTEnableCoreDevice=disabled)
    xcodebuild: error: Unable to find a destination matching the provided destination specifier:
            { id:BEB7DAD3-51B4-4725-A668-2624AC2C0207 }

        Available destinations for the "Runner" scheme:
            { platform:macOS, arch:arm64, variant:Designed for [iPad,iPhone], id:00008112-000E453A368B401E }
            { platform:iOS, id:dvtdevice-DVTiPhonePlaceholder-iphoneos:placeholder, name:Any iOS Device }

   Xcode's output:
   ↳
      Writing result bundle at path: 

/var/folders/x9/_rtfrskx74xg_mxftjrfs8qh0000gn/T/flutter_tools.tyLBdO/flutter_ios_build_temp_dirOOSm2k/temporary_xcresult_bundle


    Could not build the application for the simulator.
    Error launching application on iPhone 14 Pro Max.
```

I think the problem is something related with the build profiles according to the error shown. If so, how do I change the build profile so that the Andriod studio can find the simulation?